# Can someone explain me whats wrong with finding total part in this code

Tags: c

Whenever I run this I got something like ' 196875307' as the total, could 
someone tell me whats wrong with it.Here I uploaded the whole code.It says my post is mostly code and to add more details,So forgive me for typing these unnecessory things XD

```
#include <stdio.h>
int room;
char name[20];
int i;

void main()
{
int answr,fc[6],z=0,tot;
char ans;
char food[8][30]={"Bread","Noodles","Salad","Popcorn","Chocolate ice 
cream","Vanilla ice cream","Cold Coffee","Milk Shake"};
int price[8]={180,120,65,55,70,70,110,200};
printf("\n                        *********");
printf("\n                        MENU CARD");
printf("\n                        *********\n\n\n\n");
printf("\n              Food Code\t\tprice\t\t Food Name\n");

for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
printf("\n\t\t%d",i+1);
 printf("\t\t%d",price[i]);
printf("\t\t%s",food[i]);
}
printf("\n\n\n\t *PRESS 0 TO GO TO THE MAIN MENU\n\t *PRESS 1 TO ORDER 
FOOD");
scanf(" %d",&answr);
switch(answr)
{
case 0:
    {
        printf("Enter the main menu function here");
        break;
    }
case 1:do
{
 printf("ENTER THE FOOD CODE YOU WANT TO HAVE :: ");
 scanf(" %d",&fc[z]);
 z++;
  tot=tot+fc[z];
  printf("total so far is %d",tot);

 printf("DO YOU WANT MORE(Y/N) ::");
 scanf(" %c",&ans);

}while((ans=='y')||(ans=='Y'));
    printf("\nEnter your room number:");
    scanf(" %d",&room);
    printf("\nEnter your name:");
    scanf(" %s",&name);


}
}
```

Comment: Did you initializ `z` and `tot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in your do loop. You need to initialize tot to 0, and use the user-inputted "food code" as an array index into your price array. I don't see any use for the "fc" array you've declared. This code should work for case 1 in your switch statement.

Remember that the main function returns an int in C.

```
do {
    tot = 0;
    printf("ENTER THE FOOD CODE YOU WANT TO HAVE :: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);
    if (z < 1 || z > 8) {
        printf("Invalid food code\n");
        return -1; // main should return int in a C program
    }
    tot=tot+price[z-1];
    printf("total so far is %d\n",tot);

    printf("DO YOU WANT MORE(Y/N) ::");
    scanf(" %c",&ans);

} while((ans=='y')||(ans=='Y'));
```

Comment: theres a small issue in this code. when I enter invalid input like 10, tot becomes garbage value

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should increment your counter z after you do the addition of the total with your freshly added element into the array.
1)Get the value by scanf
2)add it by using vet[z]
3)increment z.

When your code hit the sum it will try to access to a segment of memory that is filled with some other values.

Comment: still not working.I need to mention that I have two different array for food and price. for fc I just used this `printf("\n\t\t%d",i+1);`

Comment: Is your variable z initialized to 0?

Comment: @DilshanLakshitha it seems you do not given enough source code, so give more

Comment: yes it is, I couldn't post the whole code here it says post is most of codes.

Comment: get our place, we do not have magic crystal ball ;) do not give too less

Comment: I uploaded the whole code just now.please check it.

Comment: Tot not initialized

Comment: That solved the problem, but now I have another issue. should I post another question or ask it here?

Comment: Confirm the answer first, then create a new post.